# About smd capacitors values and voltage rating

Tags: capacitor, pcb-design, power-electronics, capacitance

My Dell 3542 (2014)laptopboard got failed...i tested the board,and i found 4 smd capacitors have fialure...there is no any thing on the board to inform me about the value or voltage rating of them except the the 4 capacitors have the following numbers,c4925,c4926,c4927,c4928..can any one tell me how to know their value and voltage rating...thanks in advance...

Comment: *the following numbers,c4925,c4926,c4927,c4928* Those are the numbers of the components, these numbers are only useful when you have the **schematic**. In the schematic you can then look up how they're connected and what their ratings are. It surprises me that you don't even mention what **model** the laptop is. Dell has made hundreds of different models laptops.

Comment: Those are Reference Designators and without circuits they are meaningless. Where abouts are they?  this typically gives a clue to their function - close to an IC with traces to the top-right? probably decoupling ...

Comment: It is dell 3542(2014)

Comment: It dell 3542(2014)

Comment: 4 sequentially numbered capacitors don't all decide to blow at the same time for no reason.  Something makes them burn up.  If you replace the capacitors without removing the reason they were damaged, the replacements will probably burn up too.  Look upstream of the damaged parts and see what is supply them with voltage.  You'll probably need to replace it at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely heat damage and/or hot connect surge currents in power supply, get adequate voltage from datasheets for case size and cap value for 19.5V chargers.

Then Learn that Laptop chargers hot inserted burn out connector contacts and caps, same with USB 12W on lightning connectors, even tho no OEM ever tells anyone in public about this.!!!!!

Gold plating (flash) turns to black carbon on my lightning connectors( Apple design fault) and even vaporizes leading edge. so no wonder if your caps are PSU input related why the surge current burns Dell’s faulty design caps.  They ought to use soft start protection.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Andyaka what da ya think?

Comment: I left it in so the uninformed about lightning to USB will readily see . oh Apple !  Wow such a bad design and cheap on gold flash coating. The thumbnails certainly are a lot cleaner than mine. ;)  They just show my yesterday's new roof job 2200 sqft in 8 hrs incl plywood.  Andy are you sleeping?

Comment: FWIW, his laptop is from 2014, and so will be using the old fashioned Dell barrel jack connector rather than USB.

Comment: Of course, @user1850479 , I was expanding on a common fault ofDC hot-insertion damage from power discharge surges. Mine melted the solder on the laptop barrel-jack such that it no longer charges even after months of holding the wire under tension, at least the same vintage or more.